# Gaining immunity to physical damage

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, immunities

I know it's possible to gain immunity to e.g. conditions like poison, fear (both *Heroes Feast*), charmed, etc.
It's also possible to gain immunity to cold or fire damage, using their respective *Investiture of Ice/Flame* spells.
Immunity to psychic can be gained with *Mind Blank*.
There are also some magic items in the *DMG* that give immunities.

However, I have been unable to find anything that gives immunity to physical damage. Plenty of sources of resistance, but no immunity.
 The closest thing would be *Otiluke's Resilient Sphere*, but that does not really give you immunity, it just interposes a non-circumventable barrier between you and your enemy.

**Therefore my question: Is there any official source (both regular and unearthed arcana) that allows a PC to gain immunity to physical damage?**

To clarify: with physical damage I mean bludgeoning, slashing and piercing damage.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *Invulnerability* spell, from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (pg. 160), makes you immune to *all* damage.

Comment: To include this in the accepted question, I actually found another way of gaining immunity - the *Armor of Invulnerability*, DMG p. 152. If you want to edit that in :)

Comment: @PixelMaster For that to be part of an answer, I think you need to be more specific in the question.There isn't really any concept of "physical damage" in 5e, so I think everyone assumed you meant immunity to bludgeoning, piercing, and slashing damage. However, the Armor of Invulnerability doesn't give you that - it gives you immunity to nonmagical damage, which is quite different.

Answer (score 12):

I found another way to gain the desired immunity: you can *True Polymorph* into a creature that has immunity to physical damage.
I've made a list of creatures that have such an immunity and are available for *True Polymorph*, i.e. not above CR 20:

- Couatl (MM, p. 43)
- Demilich (MM, p. 48)
- Golems (MM, p. 167-170)
- Lycanthropes (MM, p. 208-211)
- Mummy Lord (MM, p. 229)
- Black Pudding & Ochre Jelly against slashing (MM, p. 241/243)
- Rakshasa (MM, p. 257)
- Androsphinx (MM, p. 281)

Note that most (or all, I believe) of these immunities are restricted to nonmagical physical damage, and some are bypassable with certain weapons (e.g. silvered weapons against lycanthropes).